# Puppet Module File Resource Copy From Network Mount

Tags: puppet, mount, rhel7, satellite

I'm using RHEL Satellite 6.6 with puppet 5.5.12.  I have a module which, among other things, copies a file from a network mapped folder to the local drive, then executes it.  When I run the module against the satellite server, it succeeds without a hitch.  When I apply that same module against another server (same hardware type, same OS freshly installed, non-satellite client) it dies while transferring the file with a rather useless error.  The relevant parts of the module are as follows (identifying information obfuscated):

```
$installer_name = 'installer.bin'
$installer_src  = "/mnt/svr/path/${installer_name}"
$installer_path = "/tmp/${installer_name}"
...
file { "$installer_path":
  ensure => present,
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => '0755',
  source => "${installer_src}",
  require => [ File_line['modify prop1'], File_line['modify prop2'], ]
}
```

On the satellite server when this block executes, it logs `... defined content as  '{md5}####'` and proceeds, while on the target server I get the following error:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/MODULE/File[/tmp/installer.bin]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment KT_PROG_NAME_Development_RHEL7_Core_2 source(s) file:/mnt/svr/path/installer.bin
```

On the list of things I've already attempted:

1. Changed `ensure => present,` to `ensure => file,`
2. Moved ${installer_path} down to a `path => ...` property and given the block a name.
3. Changed to `source => "file://${installer_src}",`
4. Replaced all variables with hard coded values

None have significantly changed the outcome.  I've repeatedly verified that the network mount point is present, the parent folder has 0775 perms and root:root ownership, while the file has 0755 perms and root:root ownership.

I've contemplated wrapping installer.bin up in the module's internal file path, but that is less desirable because of file sizes, program guidelines, and etc..

Otherwise, I'm running out of ideas.  The [puppet docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html#file-attribute-ensure) seem to say I'm doing it right, so at this point I'm open to trying out any suggestions the community has to offer.  Thank you!